# Like Query not working when I Use "?" character

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL query is like this

```
create table Manager(id int, managerid varchar(3) , managername varchar(50))

insert into Manager(id,managerid,managername)values(123,'A12','Mangesh')
insert into Manager(id,managerid,managername)values(54321,'A23','Sagar')
insert into Manager(id,managerid,managername)values(334,'C34','Ahmad')
insert into Manager(id,managerid,managername)values(456,'A45','Mango')
insert into Manager(id,managerid,managername)values(567,'B56','Sandesh')
```

my Like query is this

```
select * from Manager where id LIKE '%4321%'
```

this query gives me this record

```
id     managerid  managername 
54321  A23        Sagar
```

but when I try to run such kind of query it does not give me any record i.e. zero record count but actually there is one record
Query is :

```
select * from Manager where id LIKE '%?4321%'
```

what is wrong with this?

sql fiddle [sql query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da01b/4)

Comment: `?` is a special character that's why and secondly there is no data in your db that contains ?4321

Comment: select * from Manager where id LIKE '%?4321%' , why '?' is there?

Comment: I think you want to use `_` not `?`. Underscore is any single character.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee `?` is not a special character.

Comment: there is no record for '%?4321%' - as far i can see in the inserts

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4b14/4 check this fiddle

Comment: i meant wild character

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `_` not `?` for a [wildcard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179859.aspx) indicating "any single character".

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Manager WHERE id LIKE '%_4321%'
```